# Checking results of a bulk insert in elasticsearch without "ok": true

Tags: elasticsearch

1.0 removed the "ok" from responses, and I'm wondering if there's a recommended way to check if bulk inserts succeeded in the new world.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation comes with the following:

> The response to a bulk action is a large JSON structure with the
>   individual results of each action that was performed. The failure of a
>   single action does not affect the remaining actions.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: And that's exactly my problem. Before, "ok": true was part of each successful result.

Now, the complete request succeeds per http, but I don't know how to detect failures in individual requests.

At least I read the argument of removing "ok" to be that it's in the http results anyway.

Comment: Ok, sorry I thought you just wanted information about the result. Misunderstood what you wanted.